# Trouble proving a function is bijective.

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Consider a function $f$ that maps every finite subset of $\mathbb{N}_0$ the following way:
\begin{equation*}
f : \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}_0) \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0 \\[.15cm]
\{a_1,\dots,a_n\} \rightarrow 2^{a_1} + \dots + 2^{a_n}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}_0)$ denotes the set of all the finite subsets of $\mathbb{N_0}$. Also, let $f(\{\emptyset\}) = 0.$ How would one prove this is indeed a $1-1$ and onto function? (i.e., bijective). I defined this function while trying to prove $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}_0)$ is a countable set but I am having some trouble proving it is bijective, altough it makes sense in my head. For example, proving it is an onto function:
\begin{equation*}
\forall  k \in \mathbb{N}_0, \exists F \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}_0) \text{ s.t. } f(F) = k.
\end{equation*}
So, we have that $f(F) = 2^{a_1} + \dots + 2^{a_n}$ (assuming $F = \{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$). How would one solve this equation in order to $a_1,\dots,a_n$ (in order to prove it is indeed surjective? Another way to do it would be:
\begin{equation*}
f(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N}_0) = \{f(F), F \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{N_0})\} = \{0\} \cup \{2^{a_1}+\dots+2^{a_n}, \text{ where } a_1,\dots,a_n \in \mathbb{N_0}\} = \mathbb{N_0}
\end{equation*}
which is indeed quite simple. I am having more trouble proving that the function is $1-1$. i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
2^{a_1} + \dots + 2^{a_n} = 2^{b_1} + \dots + 2^{b_m} \Rightarrow \{a_1,\dots,a_n\} = \{b_1,\dots,b_m\}
\end{equation*}
How would one proceed to do so? Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: This is not a complete  answer to the question but just an observation that you are basically asking for a proof of the existence and uniqueness of the binary representation of a natural number, proofs of which should be easily available online. . For surjectivity a proof by induction will work; choose the largest power of 2 less than or equal to a given natural number $k$ and subtract from $k$. Apply the inductive hypothesis to the result.

Comment: For injectivity, you can again proceed by induction, continually dividing the number by 2. The remainders are the digits of the (unique) binary representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any number $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$. You know that this number is finite, so it also has a finite binary representation. Then $n=b_k\dots b_1 b_0$ in binary, i.e. $b_i$ is either $1$ or $0$.
For all $i$ where $b_i=1$ choose $a_j=i$ and then $f(\{a_1,\dots,a_m\})=n$, so we have proven $f$ is surjective.
For $f$ injective use $n_1\neq n_2 \Rightarrow f(n_1)\neq f(n_2)$ and observe that if $n_1\neq n_2$, they have different binary representations.

Comment: Well, $3$ in binary is $11$ and by your logic, $b_1 \text{ and } b_2 = 1 \Rightarrow F = \{1,2\} \text{ and } f(F) = 2^2 + 2 = 6 \neq 3$ ?

Comment: I believe this would work if you started $b$ indixes at $0$ instead of $1$.

Comment: Of course, start the indices at 0 and it works.

Comment: Glad you could help! Thanks for your time